# Laravel belongsTo and hasMany relationship on same model

Tags: laravel

How do you apply belongsTo and hasMany relationship on same model?

For example, I have one User and one Project model. Now Project model has method user() and User model has projects() method.

Now I want a user to share projects with other users. So that I can have methods like users() in Project model and shared_projects() in User model.

How I can achieve that?

Here is my current Project model

```
class Project extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

And this my User model

```
class Project extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function projects() {
        return $this->hasMany('Project');
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your table structure look like?

Comment: projects table has 'id', 'project_name', 'user_id' while users table has 'id', 'username', 'password'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so here it is how I solved it. I used pivot table as you suggested but I even added hasMany relationship like this way. I am still not sure what I am doing is perfectly correct but it worked. :)

```
class Project extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

And here is the key ingredient in User model

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function projects_owned() {
        return $this->hasMany('Project', 'user_id');
    }

    public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another way to do it. You can create a new column in project_user table such as ( onwer BOOL) and retrieve the user who owns the project by using where('owner',true)

Comment: Yes, but I tried my way and worked perfectly, thanks for the suggestion though, will keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 4):

In this case, User and Project have Many-to-Many relationship because one user has many projects and one project belongs to many user. Therefore, you should create a third table (project_user) which connect User table and Project table in the database. 
And you set [Many-to-Many relation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) to User Model and Project Model.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
}

}
```

In Project model

```
class Project extends Eloquent {

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}

}
```

Then you can do something like this

```
//users in the same project
$users = Project::find($id)->users;
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but doing that way I will lose hasMany relationship on projects method in User model.

Comment: Now, use the `belongsToMany` relationship  in your both models

Comment: It worked mate, see my answer missing element was to change method name and pass "foreign_key".